# Finding number ranges contained in lines

Tags: bash, awk

In this awk script I want to print out field $2 if field $5 contains any year 1900 or greater.

```
22,Grover Cleveland,http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grover_Cleveland,4/03/1885,4/03/1889,Democratic ,Grover_Cleveland_2.jpg,thmb_Grover_Cleveland_2.jpg,New York
23,Benjamin Harrison,http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benjamin_Harrison,4/03/1889,4/03/1893,Republican ,BenjaminHarrison.gif,thmb_BenjaminHarrison.gif,Indiana
24,Grover Cleveland (2nd term),http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grover_Cleveland,4/03/1893,4/03/1897,Democratic ,Grover_Cleveland.jpg,thmb_Grover_Cleveland.jpg,New York
25,William McKinley,http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/William_McKinley,4/03/1897,14/9/1901,Republican ,WilliamMcKinley.gif,thmb_WilliamMcKinley.gif,Ohio
26,Theodore Roosevelt,http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theodore_Roosevelt,14/9/1901,4/3/1909,Republican ,TheodoreRoosevelt.jpg,thmb_TheodoreRoosevelt.jpg,New York
27,William Howard Taft,http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/William_Howard_Taft,4/3/1909,4/03/1913,Republican ,WilliamHowardTaft.jpg,thmb_WilliamHowardTaft.jpg,Ohio
28,Woodrow Wilson,http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Woodrow_Wilson,4/03/1913,4/03/1921,Democratic ,WoodrowWilson.gif,thmb_WoodrowWilson.gif,New Jersey
29,Warren G. Harding,http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Warren_G._Harding,4/03/1921,2/8/1923,Republican ,WarrenGHarding.gif,thmb_WarrenGHarding.gif,Ohio
30,Calvin Coolidge,http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calvin_Coolidge,2/8/1923,4/03/1929,Republican ,CoolidgeWHPortrait.gif,thmb_CoolidgeWHPortrait.gif,Massachusetts
31,Herbert Hoover,http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Herbert_Hoover,4/03/1929,4/03/1933,Republican ,HerbertHover.gif,thmb_HerbertHover.gif,Iowa
```

This is what I am doing so far but it is giving me all the lines not just the ones containing years greater than 1900.

```
#!/bin/awk -f

BEGIN{ FS=",";
}{
if($5 >= 1900)
{ print $2;}
```

Comment: your posted sample input is unformatted and so ambiguous (where do the lines actually break?), and your posted awk script has a syntax error and so is not the one you ran that produced unexpected output and so we can't help you debug that script. please update your question to correct both things and to provide the expected output.

Answer (score 4):

The year appears in the form `4/03/1885`.  An extra step is needed to split that date and get the year:

```
$ awk -F, '{split($5,mdy,"/")} mdy[3]>=1900{print $2}' file
William McKinley
Theodore Roosevelt
William Howard Taft
Woodrow Wilson
Warren G. Harding
Calvin Coolidge
```

How it works:

- `-F,`

  Use a comma as the field separator.
- `split($5, mdy, "/")`

  Split the fifth field at `/` and place the result in the array `mdy`.
- `mdy[3]>=1900{print $2}`

  Select years greater than or equal to 1900 and print field 2.

Answer (score 1):

Another is way with using awk's match and substring functions

```
awk -v FS="," 'match($5,/[0-9]{4}/){name=substr($5,RSTART,RLENGTH)};{if(name>=1900){print $0}}'
```

results

```
25,William McKinley,http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/William_McKinley,4/03/1897,14/9/1901,Republican ,WilliamMcKinley.gif,thmb_WilliamMcKinley.gif,Ohio
26,Theodore Roosevelt,http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theodore_Roosevelt,14/9/1901,4/3/1909,Republican ,TheodoreRoosevelt.jpg,thmb_TheodoreRoosevelt.jpg,New York
27,William Howard Taft,http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/William_Howard_Taft,4/3/1909,4/03/1913,Republican ,WilliamHowardTaft.jpg,thmb_WilliamHowardTaft.jpg,Ohio
28,Woodrow Wilson,http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Woodrow_Wilson,4/03/1913,4/03/1921,Democratic ,WoodrowWilson.gif,thmb_WoodrowWilson.gif,New Jersey
29,Warren G. Harding,http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Warren_G._Harding,4/03/1921,2/8/1923,Republican ,WarrenGHarding.gif,thmb_WarrenGHarding.gif,Ohio
30,Calvin Coolidge,http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calvin_Coolidge,2/8/1923,4/03/1929,Republican ,CoolidgeWHPortrait.gif,thmb_CoolidgeWHPortrait.gif,Massachusetts
31,Herbert Hoover,http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Herbert_Hoover,4/03/1929,4/03/1933,Republican ,HerbertHover.gif,thmb_HerbertHover.gif,Iowa
```

Answer (score 0):

You have messed up with brackets:

```
#!/bin/awk -f

BEGIN{ FS=",";
}{
if($5 >= 1900) print $2;}
```